# function malloc returns NULL... but only the 10 first times

Tags: c, null, malloc

I am porting a game built in c to use opengl for porting reasons. Everything was going fine until, for some reasons, the malloc functions of the game stopped working.

I has been searching for an answer to this. The only thing I found about it is that malloc is returning NULL. A very simple malloc that creates a simple structure of a few bytes.

I made a some tries and I wrote the command inside a loop. And my surprise was that it failed the first 10 times, but after that the command worked and the game started. The structure has been created several times after that with no problem.

I would say to leave it as it is, but I am sure there is something wrong behind and in other systems may not work correctly. That's why I want to ask what kind of problem I am having, why and how to avoid it. The environment is not very friendly and I lack of debugging tools, so I would appreciate as many details as possible.

thank you.

EDIT:
The code is simple.

```
ObjectBase* newcoin;
newcoin= (ObjectBase*)calloc(1,sizeof(ObjectBase));
```

while the ObjectBase structure is very small. No more than 200 bytes.

The hardware is a windows 7 based computer with 4 GB or memory. Even with this, the error is:

```
Visual C++ CRT: Not enough memory to complete call to strerror
```

It worked fine before.
More problems. I am having the same problem when loading files from disk. It happens about 10 to 15 times and then works correctly.
The problem happens always. Each time I restart the application, it crashes.

Comment: Please, add some significant code. In that way we can't judge.

Comment: What's your environment (hardware, OS, compiler)?  Can you post some code?  Is the problem exactly reproducible?  It's unlikely but possible that the amount of available memory is actually changing, depending on what else is running.

Comment: Did you check `errno` after malloc's failure ? Also, if you are under linux (also maybe other unix) do you have a swap set up ? What does the `free` command show ?

Comment: Answered most of your questions.

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your problem but ObjectBase is not cast to any derived class is it? That would explain your symptoms of memory corruption possibly resulting in out-of-heap error.

Answer (score 0):

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug possible memory leaks in your program.

If you checked that your program is not leaking or misbehaving w.r.t. `malloc`, it may happen that [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)  returns NULL because no memory is available.

It could even happen that `malloc` returns NULL, then some third-party library releases some memory with `free`, then `malloc` could give you again some fresh memory.

You might also consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) that is use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` and not bother much about free-ing memory.

If on Linux, use the [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) pseudo-file system to learn about your process (e.g. `/proc/1234/maps` for process of pid 1234, also `/proc/self/maps` from inside the process, and `/proc/self/statm` etc). See also the `pmap` command.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I cannot rely on that because I will have to port the application to several systems that won't support those libraries. The only thing I can say is that this was working before porting to opengl and the only thing changed is the name of the structures to use the opengl ones. No reason at all to ask for more memory, specially since the application uses only about 30MB of memory.

Comment: You definitely can use `valgrind` on some systems to debug some memory leaks (and these leaks are very probably in your code, so not dependent upon the system).